# Google script select an entire row in a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to know if we can select a row in a Spreadsheet using Google script like this

[image]

Anyway first I've tried with the columns by using this fonction but I get an error of the data (is not found): If you have an idea :)

```
  function testGetFullColumn()
{
  getFullColumn('A', 1) ;
}

// This function gets the full column Range like doing 'A1:A9999' in excel
// @param {String} column The column name to get ('A', 'G', etc)
// @param {Number} startIndex The row number to start from (1, 5, 15)
// @return {Range} The "Range" object containing the full column: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range
function getFullColumn(column, startIndex){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  return sheet.getRange(column+startIndex+':'+column+lastRow);
}
```

Edit :I know about getRange but I would be cool^^^^^^ to see in visually the selection like in the photo I've attached because I tried with

`var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; return sheet.getDataRange();`

and it doesn't select all the sheet visually I mean I want to see an interactive selection :) like  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNduZ.png)

Edit 2: I've tried to use setActiveRange after getRange as you suggested thanks Guilherme M but it doesn't select visually all the document :( Your code works it's really cool^ [I was afraid that it's impossible to select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNi4S.png) I will try to do the same thanks ^^

```
 function testGet()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range =  sheet.getDataRange();
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(range)
}
```

Edit 3: To select all the document I've tried this code:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
 var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
 
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,lastRow+1,lastColumn+1);
 sheet.setActiveRange(range);

 var selection = sheet.getSelection();
 // Current cell: A1
 var currentCell = selection.getCurrentCell();
 // Active Range: tout le document
 var activeRange = selection.getActiveRange();
```

Comment: You should try [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))

Comment: Yes I know about getRange but I would be cool^^^^^^ to see in visually the selection like in the photo I've attached because I tried with   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  return sheet.getDataRange(); and it doesn't select all the sheet visually I mean I want to see an interactive selection :)

Comment: Oh, well then you use [setActiveRange(range)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setactiverangerange) after `getRange()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can select a row or any range in the spreadsheet using Apps Script. You do so with method [`setActiveRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#setactiverangerange). An example follows below:

```
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var range = sheet.getRange('A1:D4');
 sheet.setActiveRange(range);

 var selection = sheet.getSelection();
 // Current cell: A1
 var currentCell = selection.getCurrentCell();
 // Active Range: A1:D4
 var activeRange = selection.getActiveRange();
```

**Notice** The method [`getDataRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange()) selects range "in which data is present.", so it won't select blank cells or the whole document. For such task, you need method [`getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)) combined with [`getMaxRows()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getMaxRows()) and [`getMaxColumns()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getMaxColumns()).

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns());
sheet.setActiveRange(range);

var selection = sheet.getSelection();
// Current cell: A1
var currentCell = selection.getCurrentCell();
// Active Range: A1:D4
var activeRange = selection.getActiveRange();
```

Comment: Thanks it worked ^^^^I've tried to do the same with the whole document

Comment: var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
 var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
 
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,lastRow+1,lastColumn+1);
 sheet.setActiveRange(range);

 var selection = sheet.getSelection();
 // Current cell: A1
 var currentCell = selection.getCurrentCell();
 // Active Range: tout le document
 var activeRange = selection.getActiveRange(); if I don't put +1 I will get an error of data definition it can't find it and you also used currentCell  as variable we have to put it?

Comment: @anamaria Why are you adding 1 inside the range? If you see `getRange()`, it is actually **how many** rows and columns you want to get. By the way, this is not place to "chat". You can reach me and others in Google Apps Script community in G+

Answer (score 0):

To do that you show in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fO1G.png) i use this:

```
function myFunction2() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange( 2 + ':' + 2 ).activate();
};
```

and if you want to make it variable so, add a variable like n:

```
function myFunction2() {
  var n = 2
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange( n + ':' + n ).activate();
};
```

the way to manage range, rows and columns, are in the other answer.